# Are foreign workers who work in a US-based company required to pay US taxes?

Tags: united-states, tax-law

US-based company A hires worker B, who is a citizen and resident of country C and does not travel to the US for work.
Will the US government collect any taxes (income, Social Security, Medicare, etc) on B?

Comment: Generally not. See [IRS Publication 519, “U.S. Tax Guide for Aliens.”](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p519.pdf)

Comment: Also [IRS Publication 515, “Withholding of Tax on Nonresident Aliens and Foreign entities”](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p515.pdf)

Comment: See also Internal Revenue Code Section 911 (exempting most foreign earned income of U.S. citizens from taxation). https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/911 The exclusion is up to $108,700 per year in 2021.

Comment: We assume that the U.S.-based company is not an agency or instrumentality of the United States government (e.g. AMTRAK, the U.S. Post Office, or the Tennessee Valley Authority). Income from those companies are subject to U.S. income taxation.

Answer (score 2):

### No

The company is hiring and paying the worker in country C. They will need to withhold and remit taxes, insurance etc. in accordance with local law. They may also be required to pay in local currency - some jurisdictions require employees to be paid in cash which means local money, not US dollars.

By the way, this is the same if B were a US citizen living in C. The only difference is that B would be required to submit tax returns (and possibly pay tax) for the US as well as C.

Comment: And usually not even then. Most foreign earned income of U.S. citizens is exempt from U.S. taxation.

Comment: @ohwilleke if I remember correctly, the foreign earned income exclusion doesn't relieve the US citizen from the requirement to file a tax return even if the tax liability is zero as a result of the exclusion.

Comment: @phoog Incorrect. Since it is an exclusion, as opposed to a foreign tax credit (which is how other foreign income is treated under U.S. law) foreign earned income within the exclusion doesn't even have to be reported.